# Display a string variable in view and change it when a view is rendered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to store a variable which will be changed when a view is rendered. It's a text in my header which tells me what page I am on (Home, register, login, etc). Here's an example:

Home (root of the website):

[image]

Register (/authentication/register)

[image]

I tried storing the variable in my base (root) view with `<%= $header_title = "AppName" %>` Like this:

My code (application.html.erb):

```
<%= $header_title = "AppName" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title><%= t('app') %></title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <%= render 'layouts/header.html.erb'%>
    </header>

<main>
    <%= yield %>
</main>


</body>
</html>
```

But when I do this, this happens to the document (`AppName` is just a placeholder):

[image]

I don't want it to put the string above the header in the document like that, instead I am just trying to store that variable and then use it in the header text.

Here's the "layouts/_header.html.erb"

```
<div id="header-body">
<div id="title-body" class="header-item-padding">
    <p><%= $header_title %></p>
</div>
<div id="navigation-body" class="header-item-padding">

<%= isloggedin = false
    if isloggedin == false
        render 'layouts/header/navigationRegister.html.erb'
    else
        if userIsAdmin = false
            render 'layouts/header/navigationUser.html.erb'
        else
            render 'layouts/header/navigationAdmin.html.erb'
        end
    end %>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show an example of the code you are using and the actual output, not just a description of the output. Also include an example of the actual output you desire. Or do you not want ANY output, just have the variable available in the header? Your question is unclear.

Comment: Oh! Let me edit it right now, sorry!

Comment: I've edited it as best as I can, hopefully it's a bit easier to understand now.

Comment: It's because you've explicitly told it to render the string `AppName`.

Comment: I see, I am clearly doing something wrong. Where should I store the variable then?

Comment: You need to post your 'layouts/header.html.erb' code

Comment: Done. Added it to the bottom.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98503/discussion-between-beartech-and-sebastian-olsen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the entire line

```
<% headerTitle = "AppName" %>
```

and in `layouts/header.html.erb`

```
<div id="header-body">
<div id="title-body" class="header-item-padding">
  <p><%= action_name.titleize %></p>
</div>
<div id="navigation-body" class="header-item-padding">
```

The variable action_name is available to you and you interpolate it here into something like "register". The `.titleize` action makes it more human readable like "Register". In the case of multi word controllers it will change something like "user_registration" into "User Registration" where `.capitalize` will give you "User_Registration".

Answer (score 1):

Delete the `<%= headerTitle = "AppName" %>` and concentrate on the `<%= render 'layouts/header.html.erb'%>` instead.

Rails allows local variables, like so:

```
<%= render 'layouts/header.html.erb', locals: { x: :value_of_x } %>
```

So there is a nice global variable which is `controller_name` which resembles the name of the controller. You only need to *capitalize* it but rails has a method for this either, so in your case it would be:

```
<%= render 'layouts/header.html.erb', locals: { app_name: controller_name.capitalize } %>
```

And in your partial you can use `app_name` then. Like `<span><%= app_name %></span>` or whereever you need the name of the Controller.

I hope this helps.

Comment: So I tried this, but when refreshing the page I get this error: http://puu.sh/m2Pjy/6b4f969c79.png

Comment: Is this `header_title` the same name you use in the `render` action? Because then it should be `<%= render 'layouts/header.html.erb', locals: { header_title: controller_name.capitalize } %>`

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `=`.

```
<% headerTitle = "AppName" %>
```

Then the `headerTitle` won't be rendered in your page.

BTW by Ruby convention you should use camel case for variable names. So in your case `header_title`.

Happy coding :)

Comment: Ah thanks! So I assume changing the variable in the views is okay, or is there a better way? Edit: Attempting to change the variable in the views is not doing anything.

Comment: Take a deeper look into the MVC architecture. It always depends on what you want to do. But you should try to keep the view clean. You should try to keep the logic in your controllers and helper methods for your views in helper modules. So in your case, you probably should move the `headerTitle` into the controller.

Comment: I tried doing this before, but it threw a syntax error. Could you refresh me on the correct syntax for this? Simply putting "$header_title = "blahblah" in the class (or controller) doesn't work.

Comment: As I said, it depends on what you are trying to do but in your case, I would probably create a `before_action`. Could you explain what you try to achieve exactly?